# Is it possible to get a notification when observable is completed for cold stream?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am writing an http filter that works on a stream:

```
override fun handleStream(ctx: StreamServerRequestContext): Observable<T> {
    counter.incrementAndGet()
    val observable: Observable<T> = ctx.invokeStream<T>()
    observable.subscribe(object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
            val dec = counter.decrementAndGet()
            logger.info { "value after error dec $dec" }
        }

        override fun onNext(t: T) {
        }

        override fun onCompleted() {
            val dec = counter.decrementAndGet()
            logger.info { "value after dec $dec" }
        }
    })
    return observable
}
```

I would like to increase a counter before the request and decrease it after. Since it is working with cold stream the effect is that the observable code is executed twice with the above code.

Can I "listen" to stream completion without actually invoking it again?

Comment: The code is likely not doing what you think it is. First, you subscribe to `observable` which activates the observer chain. Then you return the `observable` from `handleStream()` where you presumably subscribe to it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `doFinally` operator:

```
override fun <T> handleStream(ctx: StreamServerRequestContext): Observable<T> {
    counter.incrementAndGet()
    return ctx.invokeStream<T>()
        .doFinally {
            val dec = counter.decrementAndGet()
            logger.info { "value after dec $dec" }
        }
}
```